# Commonly used metrics to compare two Young measures

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, measure-theory, calculus-of-variations

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded open set, $K\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be a compact set, and $M_1(K)$ be the set of probability measures on $K$. Then  a Young measure is defined as a $\textrm{weak}^*$ measurable map:
$$
\nu:x\in \Omega\mapsto \nu(x)\in M_1(K).
$$

Now I want to compare two Young measures $\nu$ and $\mu$. However, since there are many distances defined on $M_1(K)$, I am not sure what is the most commonly used metric for Young measures. Is the choice of metric  problem dependent?

In particular, I am interested in the case where $K$ is not finite. Since if $K$ is a finite set with cardinality $N$, then I can identify $M_1(K)$ as the probability simplex in $\mathbb{R}^N$, and hence view $\nu$ as a function
$$
\nu:x\in \Omega\to \nu(x)\in \mathbb{R}^N,
$$
and use the metric $\|\nu-\mu\|=\sup_{x\in \Omega}\|\nu(x)-\mu(x)\|_{\mathbb{R}^N}$, where $\|\cdot\|_{\mathbb{R}^N}$ denotes the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^N$.

---

I found in the literature that one can use the norm 
$\|\nu\|_{\textrm{TV}}=\sup_{x\in \Omega}|\nu(x)|_{\textrm{TV}}$, where $|\cdot|_{\textrm{TV}}$ denotes the total variation norm of a probability measure. However,  the TV norm seems to be too strong for my application. In particular, $(M_1(K),|\cdot|_{\textrm{TV}})$ is not separable if $K$ is uncountable, so it is not easy to approximate $M_1(K)$ by a finite dimensional sub-manifold and obtain convergence in $\|\cdot\|_{\textrm{TV}}$-norm.

Comment: I may be biased here due to the fact that my privileged topics these days is optimal transport, but have you tried Monge-Kantorovich-Wasserstein distances? You can approximate any probability measure by empiric (point) measures, and in fact convergence in such distances is roughly equivalent to weak (AKA "narrow" or "weak-*") convergence of measures (plus convergence of some moments)